# Stop bower from asking for statistics when installing

Tags: bower

I'm trying to set up an automated package build for an app which uses bower.  When it gets to bower install in the postinstall, bower prompts:

> [?] May bower anonymously report usage statistics to improve the tool
>   over time? (Y/n)

This is screwing up the automated scripts.  I could write an expect script to deal with this but I'd rather not if I don't have to.  Is there a way to get it to shut up?

Comment: It's being discussed here: https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/1102

Comment: I've got the same problem, but I can't type Y or N to answer the question in PowerCmd, or in the native windows command prompt. Anyone else have this problem?  Or should this be a new question?

Answer (score 62):

As was noted in a comment, this was raised as [an issue at github](http://github.com/bower/bower/issues/1102). At the end of that issue there's reference to a minor note at the end of the [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/bower/bower/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#130---2014-03-10) comments:

> *NOTE*: It's advisable that users use `--config.interactive=false` on automated scripts.

Comment: Would be helpful if they actually added that to the bower --help documentation!

Comment: so I think this disables stats reporting?  [PR] Bypass Bower interaction, it's hanging the deploy script #108 https://github.com/genesis/wordpress/pull/108

Answer (score 25):

You can create a `~/.bowerrc` file, which is useful when using bower to install components in a Docker environment:

```
{
  "interactive": false
}
```

Another option is setting an environment variable ([source](http://bower.io/docs/api/#running-on-a-continuous-integration-server)):

```
export CI=true
```

Comment: The problem on using this on the bowerrc is that also you wont have a prompt whenever you install something and you need to resolve a conflict with versions for example.

Answer (score 9):

It seems that you could use

```
bower --config.analytics=false install
```

to disable **only** Analytics question.

@see https://github.com/bower/bower/pull/1470

Comment: Better answer than the first one :)

Comment: That is exactly my user case and solves my problem. Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the existing answers, note that when you are running bower from grunt (e.g. with `grunt bower-install-simple`, you'll have to add this not into any .bowerrc file, but into the Gruntfile.js. I recently added this line to prevent our CI getting stuck due to unresolvable dependencies:

```
 grunt.initConfig({
     ...,
     /**
      * Downloads and installs library dependencies via bower
      * defined in bower.json.
      */
     'bower-install-simple': {
         options: {
             ...,
+            interactive: false
         }
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

General way to bypass input for most commands: `yes`.

```
yes | bower install
yes | grunt build
```